# Нужна помощь в ускорении метода слияния элементов коллекции

Tags: java, алгоритм, коллекции

Есть метод который хранит объекты заявок типа:

```
class Order {
    private String book;
    private String operation;
    private int volume;
    private float price;
    private int orderId;

    Order(String book,
          String operation,
          int volume,
          float price,
          int orderId) {

        this.book = book;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.price = price;
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
    // гетеры сетеры
}
```

Есть метод который проверяет что у двух объектов `Order` поле `price` одинаковое, а `book` и `operation` разные, и если это так, то проводит операцию автоматически.

Ну на пример: есть два `Order` у которых

1ый ордер - `price = 10`, `operation = "SELL"`, `volume = 100`, `book = "book-1"`;

2ой ордер - `price = 10`, `operation = "BUY"`, `volume = 130`, `book = "book-2"`;

Тогда 1ый ордер вообще исчезает а у второго `volume` становится `30`

Либо если `volume` у обоих был один и тот-же они оба исчезают.

Либо если у первого ордера `volume` был больше на `20` то второй исчезает, а у первого становится `20`.

Главное что `price` одинаковые и заявки с разными `book` и `operation`. Сколько смог купил/продал, что не смог, та часть запроса осталась.

Вот моя реализация:

```
private Collection<Order> automaticDeal(List<Order> orders) {
    for (int i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < orders.size(); j++) {

            if (bookNonEquals(orders.get(i), orders.get(j)) &&
                    operationEquals(orders.get(i), orders.get(j)) &&
                    priseEquals(orders.get(i), orders.get(j))
                    ) {

                if (orders.get(i).getVolume() < orders.get(j).getVolume()) {
                    int volume = orders.get(j).getVolume() - orders.get(i).getVolume();
                    orders.get(j).setVolume(volume);
                    orders.remove(i);
                }

                if (orders.get(i).getVolume() > orders.get(j).getVolume()) {
                    int volume = orders.get(i).getVolume() - orders.get(j).getVolume();
                    orders.get(i).setVolume(volume);
                    orders.remove(j);
                }

                if (orders.get(i).getVolume() == orders.get(j).getVolume()) {
                    orders.remove(j);
                    orders.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(orders);
}

private boolean bookNonEquals(Order fst, Order snd) {
    return !fst.getBook().equals(snd.getBook());
}

private boolean operationEquals(Order fst, Order snd) {
    return fst.getOperation().equals(snd.getOperation());
}

private boolean priseEquals(Order fst, Order snd) {
    return fst.getPrice() == snd.getPrice();
}
```

Но она работает неприемлемо медленно. А как поправить не знаю, может быть использовать `parallelStream()` или еще как-то, не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста ускорить выполнение метода на сколько возможно у меня там 3 млн. объектов.

Comment: первое что бросается в глаза - методы get(int index) у листов могут выполняться за O(n) времени(для ArrayList время O(1)), а remove(Object o) для, например, ArrayList требует сдвига всех элементов после удаляемого влево на одну позицию. и есть ли смысл пересоздавать список чтобы вернуть его?

Comment: @Никита Гордеев я ArrayList туда посылаю, все-таки get() у меня явно чаще вызывается. Мне кажется надо как то попытаться в паралельных потоках это вычислять но как не знаю...

Comment: все равно стоит избавиться от вызова remove(), слишком дорогая операция. как вариант создать сразу новый список и добавлять в него нужные элементы и сразу задать размер списка(для ArrayList сэкономит время на пересоздании более длинного списка) примерно того размера, который ожидаете увидеть.

Comment: либо еще один вариант - использовать LinkedList, для него удаление элемента будет проходить быстрее, но цикл заменить итератором, для LinkedList получение следующего элемента должно проходить за O(1)

Comment: Воспользуйтесь 'Map<Integer,Collection<Order>>', где ключ - значение price у каждого order'a. В ней группируете все заявки, а потом находите общую сумму. Во-первых, если мапа большая - ее тогда можно распараллелить. Во-вторых, какая-то странная у вас, логика, т.к. нет смысла в такой группировке, ибо в конечном счёте теряются данные о названии в поле 'book'

Comment: @I. Perevoz я в начале так и хотел и идея с многопоточностью оттуда появилась, но реализовать не как не получается все время запутываюсь...